# onTouchListener is not working

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

**CODE :**

```
public class ImageActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ImageView mClickedImage;
    PhotoViewAttacher mPhotoViewAttacher;
    TextView mRotate_imageActivity;
    private int BASEINT_ImageActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String string = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("Clicked Image");
        mClickedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_clicked_image);
        mRotate_imageActivity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_rotate_imageActivity);

        mPhotoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mClickedImage);

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(string)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(mClickedImage);

        mRotate_imageActivity.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(string)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .transform(new RotateHelper(getApplicationContext(), 90f))
                            .into(mClickedImage);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**XML CODE:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.keepair.www.pinair.ImageActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rl_rotate_text">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_rotate_imageActivity"
            android:text="@string/rotate"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iv_clicked_image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see above, my xml code says that textview is on imageview. They are lapped.

But i think, because of photoviewattacher, that onTouchListener what has been written for TextView, mRotate_imageActivity do not works.

**Question :** How can i make onTouchListener works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `update` in your `PhotoViewAttacher` after changing the image of that `ImageView`

```
// If you later call mImageView.setImageDrawable/setImageBitmap/setImageResource/etc then you just need to call
mAttacher.update();
```

In your case, you can attach a listener to Glide to know when the image got loaded and update the `PhotoViewAttacher` there.

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
     .load(args.getString(IMAGE_TO_SHOW))
     .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
         @Override
         public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
             mAttacher.update();
             return false;
         }
     })
     .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Where do i add it?  please would you let me know?